# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I'm trying to run a flask code that would upload an excel file and display its contents on my local browser. This is the code :

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import os
import pandas as pd

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key="123"

app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER1"]="static/excel"

@app.route("/display",methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_file = request.files['upload_excel']
        if upload_file.filename != '':
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER1"], upload_file.filename)
            upload_file.save(file_path)
            data=pd.read_excel(upload_file)
            return render_template("ExcelFile.html",data=data.to_html(index=False).replace('<th>','<th style="text-align:center">'))
    return render_template("UploadExcel.html")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now when I run this on VS Code, this error pops up : **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'**

This is the error message in the problem tab of VS Code : **Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylance(reportMissingModuleSource)**

I've tried multiple solutions, I'll list them here :

1. "pip install wheel"
2. "pip install pandas --upgrade"
3. Restarting VS Code
4. Uninstalling and reinstalling python in my device

Nothing has worked. All show "Requirement already satisfied".
My interpreter is Python 3.10.4 64-bit, if it helps.
HELP! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run "pip show pandas". What will terminal show? And make sure that the pandas version matches the python version

Comment: It shows the pandas version is 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned the interpreter is (Python 3.10.4 64-bit). This makes me feel you are not using the venv interpreter but the global one. Are you sure you are using the correct interpreter in vscode?

You mentioned you are installing to a venv. But maybe the interpreter is not set to that in vscode.

Check this out to select the interpreter: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters

Comment: Thanks mate! This helped. I'm now able to run the code. Appreciate it!!

Comment: You are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling pandas? You could also try

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas
```

If you're working in a venv, make sure you're installing to the venv and not just to the system library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried it and it's not working and I'm installing it to the venv.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the path of pandas correctly?

**error message in the problem tab of VS Code : Import "pandas" could not be resolved from sourcePylance(reportMissingModuleSource)**

This means vscode doesn't recognize it.

You could add pandas'path in the settings manually.

[image]

Comment: Another solution helped, but thanks a lot for your help!